# Exporting the file along with unicode support the file extension is .po

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working on a translation application. This application translates strings in to different languages. After translation, I am storing the values of translated string in to database. I want to export the file along with unicode values. The exported file extension is .po. How should I do that?

Comment: Where's the problem? Getting data out of the database? Saving them UTF-8 encoded? Naming a file with an extension .po? Saving data in .po *format*?

Comment: Saving them UTF-8 encoded format?

Comment: `mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8`

Comment: i am currently working on a translation plugin for cakephp applications (and export from translated content to the /locale/ .po files). you might want to pool resources, if your application isn't supposed to be too different.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand anything about GNU gettext and .po language translation format? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_gettext